# If $P_1$ and $P_2$ are orthogonal projectors, then $\mathrm{tr}(P_1 P_2) \leq \mathrm{rk}(P_1 P_2).$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, orthogonality, orthogonal-matrices, projection-matrices

> **Prove or provide a counterexample:**  If $P_1$ and $P_2$ are orthogonal projectors, then $\mathrm{tr}(P_1 P_2) \leq \mathrm{rk}(P_1 P_2),$ where $\mathrm{tr}$ denoted the trace and $\mathrm{rk}$ the rank.

*Some attempt.* Since $P_1$ is an orthogonal projector, $P_1 = P_1^\intercal = P_1^2.$ We can orthogonally diagonalise
$$
P_1 = x_1 x_1^\intercal + \ldots + x_k x_k^\intercal = XX^\intercal,
$$
where $X = [x_1, \ldots, x_k]$ and the $x_i$ are *orthonormal* and they span the image of $P_1.$ Then
$$
\mathrm{tr}(P_1 P_2) = \mathrm{tr}(X^\intercal P_2 X) = \sum_{i = 1}^k x_i^\intercal P_2 x_i.
$$
The right hand side is $\leq k = \mathrm{rk}(P_1)$ since $x_i^\intercal P_2 x_i = \|P_2 x_i\|^2 \leq \|x_i\|^2 = 1.$ This, of course, does not prove the result.

*Partial solution.* If $P_1P_2 = P_2 P_1,$ then $P_1 P_2$ is the orthogonal projector onto the intersection of the images of $P_1$ and $P_2$ (see my other question: [decomposition of projectors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4444949/oblique-projection-onto-an-intersection-along-to-a-sum-of-vector-spaces/4447826#4447826)). In this case, we want to prove $\mathrm{tr}(P) \leq \mathrm{rk}(P)$ which is true since all eigenvalues of $P$ are either zero or one and therefore the two numbers coincide.

Therefore, if there is a counterexample, it has to be one for which $P_1 P_2 \neq P_2 P_1$ and this means (proved in the same question linked above), with $V_i = \mathrm{Im}(P_i),$
$$
V_1 \neq (V_1 \cap V_2) \oplus (V_1 \cap V_2^\perp) \qquad \text{(equiv., } V_2 \neq (V_1 \cap V_2) \oplus (V_1^\perp \cap V_2 \text{).}
$$

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but it seems to me that $P_1P_2$ is also orthogonal so all its eigenvalues have module 1. Hence $|tr(P_1P_2)|  <= n$. At the same time $P_1P_2$ is isomorphism so its rank is n.

Comment: @Salcio the $P_i$ are orthogonal __projectors__ (as opposed to oblique projectors). They are not orthogonal __operators__.

Comment: As I said I maybe missing something ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It suffices to assume that $P_1$ is an orthogonal projector and $P_2$ is any matrix that satisfies $0\preceq P_2\preceq I$. Then $0\preceq P_1P_2P_1\,(\preceq P_1IP_1=P_1^2=P_1)\preceq I$. Therefore $\operatorname{tr}(P_1P_2P_1)\le\operatorname{rank}(P_1P_2P_1)$ (if you don't see this, think about the unitary diagonalisation of $P_1P_2P_1$) and in turn
$$
\operatorname{tr}(P_1P_2)
=\operatorname{tr}(P_1^2P_2)
=\operatorname{tr}(P_1P_2P_1)
\le\operatorname{rank}(P_1P_2P_1)
\le\operatorname{rank}(P_1P_2).
$$

Comment: Of course! The trace of $P_1P_2$ is the same of $P_1P_2P_1$ (I did have this) and since this matrix is symmetric, it is orthogonally diagonalisable. That means that it can be written as a sum of $\mu_i E_i$ where the $E_i$ are mutually orthogonal orthonal projectors whose sum is the identity. Such a clear and clean answer!

Comment: By the way, if $P$ is idempotent and symmetric, then $P$ is an orthogonal projector since then $P^t(I-P)=0.$ I am assuming that the funny inequality sign you used meant the partial order on positive semi- definite matrices, which are symmetric as far as I knew.

Answer (score 2):

$\big \Vert P_1P_2\big \Vert_2\leq \big \Vert P_1\big \Vert_2\cdot \big \Vert P_2\big \Vert_2 \leq 1$
i.e. operator 2 norm is submultiplicative and a non-zero orthogonal projection has operator 2 norm of 1.  This means all eigenvalues of $(P_1P_2)$, which are necessarily real (why?), satisfy $\lambda_i\in [0,1]$

Then $(P_1P_2)$ has $n$ eigenvalues, $k$ of which are non-zero
$ \text{trace}\big(P_1P_2\big) =\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i= \sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i\leq \sum_{i=1}^k 1 = \text{rank}\big(P_1P_2\big)$

since $P_1P_2$ is diagonalizable, ref: [A and B are real, symmetric and positive semi-definite matrices of the same order; is AB diagonalizable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3621512/a-and-b-are-real-symmetric-and-positive-semi-definite-matrices-of-the-same-orde/)

note: the fact that $\big(P_1P_2\big)$ is diagonalizable is nice but technically not needed. If the matrix were defective its rank would be bounded below by the number of non-zero eigenvalues, $k$.